# Which piano piece is played here?

Tags: knowledge, music

The picture shows a typical pattern of a piano piece.
Which piano piece is played here?

[image]

Hint1:

> here is another part of the piece from the very beginning:
>
>   [image]

Hint2:

> here are the notes for the first pattern:
>
>   [image]

Comment: The bottom notes of the beginning hint look like octaves of F-G-A. Which sounds like Frere Jacque. But I don't recognize anything else.

Comment: @Daniel: sorry, but nothing to do with Frere Jacque, The tempo for those octaves is "presto con fuoco" .

Comment: Well I think there are four sharps (key of E), so the beginning looks like F# G# A G# A B, which sounds familiar but I can't ID it. In the top picture the right key just seems to be doing a scale.

Comment: Is there more to this than just converting the synthesia notation into block notation?

Comment: It's not a piano piece (though I often play it on one) but it reminds me of Onpu'f Gbppngn (va q zvabe, gur bar jvgu gur shthr).

Comment: I added another hint, I hope it helps further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Through some internet research, I was able to determine that the piano piece is:

> Chopin Scherzo No. 3
>
>  For example, if you look at [the sheet music for it at this site](https://musopen.org/music/140-scherzo-no-3-in-c-sharp-minor-op-39/) and turn to page 3 of the sheet music, the part listed in Hint2 is located there.

Comment: Tricky.  I was searching for D flat major instead of C sharp minor.

Comment: @JS1, congrats, you solved it! It is op 39, finished in 1839, and Chopin was 39 years old when he passed away...

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer, but I couldn't fit it into a comment.

I transcribed the sheet music in Hint2 into ABC notation.  Copy the ABC notation below and paste it into to [this ABC player/editor page](https://www.abcjs.net/abcjs-editor.html), and then press the play button to hear the music.  I didn't recognize it myself, but maybe someone will recognize it after hearing it.

```
X: 1
T: Unknown Piano Piece
M: 3/4
L: 1/8
K: Db bass
V: 1
A,6-|[A, F,]6-|[D,6 F,6 D6] | [E,A,CE]6 | L[F,A,DF]2 [K: treble] b'f'a'd' | g'd'f'ae'a|d'fbfad|gdfAeA|[Fd]2 z2 z2|
V: 2 clef=bass
A,,6-|[D,,A,,D,]6 | [B,,,B,,]6 | [A,,,A,,]6 | L[D,,,D,,]2 [K: treble] d'fad |adfAfA|dFdFAD|ADFA,FA,|[K:bass]D,2 z2 z2|
```